# VS2010 Pre-Build script exiting with code 1?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have the following script set as my VS2010 pre-build script:

```
cd "$(ProjectDir)"
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  "$(ProjectDir)Build.ps1"
```

Can someone please explain why it exits with a code of 1 and throws a build error?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell returns an exit code of 1 when there is an uncaught THROW in a script. If you're sure this isn't the case (or you aren't concerned with it), you can always end your script with `EXIT 0`